# How to upload bulk data in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, upload, logstash, kibana, bulk

Can anybody knows the process to upload bulk data in elastic search, I am not able to upload data in elastic search.

Thanks 
Gaurav Singh

Answer (score 0):

```
from elasticsearch import helpers, Elasticsearch

data = [{'id':1, 'content':'some content'}]
INDEX_NAME = 'index'
TYPE = 'list'

def get_actions():
    actions = []
    for d in data:
       action = {
            '_op_type': 'update',
            "_index": INDEX_NAME,
            '_type': TYPE,
            "_id": d['id'],
        }
        actions.append(action)
    return(actions)

result  = helpers.bulk(Elasticsearch(IP), get_actions())
```